# How to let a Python program raise an alarm whenever a floating-point overflow or underflow occurs?

Tags: python, floating-point, floating-point-exceptions

I have a python program P that calls numpy, scipy and many other libraries in scientific computing. I can modify program P but cannot modify the libraries it calls.

Now I want the program P raises an alarm whenever a floating-point overflow or underflow occurs. How can I do that?

An example of overflow is to compute an exponential function e^x when x is large. But that exponential function is not something I can touch. It maybe called indirectly,  so checking the return value or parameter of the function is not doable. Also there might be other numerical functions that cause overflow. So I am looking for a systematic way to detect floating-point overflow at run time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the method `seterr`.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html

```py
import numpy as np

np.seterr(over='raise')

np.exp(1000000)
```